# Can't create package.json

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, npm

Even I tried the Set-execution policies to unrestricted which resolved my dummy serve error but can't create `package.json`.

OUTPUT is pasted below. Please note: I tried both `npm init` and `npm init -y`

```sh
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> npm init -y
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\package.json'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\package.json'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\package.json'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-14T08_03_04_050Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try to open the PowerShell window as an administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a `package.json` because you are under `C:\Windows\System32`.  Windows is stopping you from creating your own files where it keeps system files.

Change to another directory (prefereably one under `C:\Users\YourUsernameHere\` and try again.